# Add Same Data to Multiple LineCharts

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am Using SceanBulder and i input two Linechart into it. But when i try to add data to both of them only one get data and other dont please help 
this is the FxmlController code

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
private LineChart<Number, Number> C1;
@FXML
private LineChart<Number, Number> C2;
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series.setName("Data Series");
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1,2));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2,3));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(3,4));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(4,5));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(5,6));
    C1.setTitle("C1");
    C2.setTitle("C2");
    C1.getData().add(series);
    C2.getData().add(series);
}    

}
```

This is fxml code

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="513.0" prefWidth="490.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="myexample.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
  <FlowPane layoutX="6.0" prefHeight="522.0" prefWidth="500.0">
     <children>
        <LineChart fx:id="C1" prefHeight="236.0" prefWidth="500.0">
          <xAxis>
            <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
          </xAxis>
          <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
          </yAxis>
        </LineChart>
        <LineChart fx:id="C2" prefHeight="260.0" prefWidth="500.0">
          <xAxis>
            <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
          </xAxis>
          <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
          </yAxis>
        </LineChart>
     </children>
  </FlowPane>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is the output:

[image: This is the output]

See one chart is empty even though I added its details

I tried everything I know of.

Comment: A major flaw of the Chart API is that the `XYChart.Data` class references the node used to display the data in the UI. Since a node can only be part of the scene graph once, this means a data set cannot be used in multiple charts. (This is the major reason I don't recommend the Chart API for production code.) So, unfortunately here, you'll have to create a second copy of your series, and a second copy of the `XYChart.Data` points within it.

Comment: One option to manage this elegantly would be to encapsulate your data in an application-specific model. Then create series which observe the model and are updated when the data change. That way you can have a single data model instance, and multiple chart/series instances observing it. You just need to be careful to only update the data through the model, not through the series.

Comment: unrelated: java naming convention, please! BTW: considerable improvement (in regard to how-to ask) against your previous questions :)

Comment: .. but you should have _edited_ your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61266225/203657) with the same problem (vs. creating a new one)

Comment: Sorry@kleopatra

Comment: @James_D Thank you very much your answer worked.i created another series and it work fine.but now when adding multiple series to single Linechart 2nd and Third series's Names are shown as 0?? Can you help me fix this too

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing ;)